# Disable login for specific user

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to disable specific user accounts from logging in. I can't remove the account because the user should be able to access all his old records when he is enabled again.

I've made a fork of parse-server and edited the `UsersRouter` to achieve what I want. See the changes [on my github fork](https://github.com/Mardaneus86/parse-server/commit/c7cdd19105dcb57f60dc9233850baedab473d6ed). How would the Parse community feel about such an addition? Since I couldn't find any existing workaround, I'm wondering if the community needs something like this.

Now I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this? Another option I thought of would be to create a cloud function that would handle the login and return a session token, combined with a `become` call on the client side. But that has other negative side effects as well.

So the question comes down to: what is the best way to disable a user in Parse without deleting the user?

I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/3565) with a proposal on the parse-server repository on GitHub as well.

Comment: Just set ACL to achieve this!

Comment: As you can see in the comments of the Github issue I created, the ACL is reset to the users ID whenever I try to remove it. This only happens on the User object and not on other objects. Don't know what causes that behavior.

Comment: create restrict role and add user to role, then use CLP for that role

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `beforeLogin()` trigger has been added  starting from v3.3.0:
https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#beforelogin

```js
Parse.Cloud.beforeLogin(async request => {
  const { object: user }  = request;
  if(user.get('isBanned')) {
   throw new Error('Access denied, you have been banned.')
  }
});
```

Comment: No longer using Parse, but this probably solves the issue. So accepting the answer for future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ughh I hate parse server, that said, the following solution somewhat works for me;

1) Ban user:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
import * as randomstring from 'randomstring';
import { createReportQuery } from './reportQuery';
import mongoExecute from 'helpers/mongo';

export async function handleBanUserRequest(req, res) {

    const userId = req.body.userId;
    if (!userId) {
        res.status(400).send('User id cant be empty');
        return;

    }

    const user = await mongoExecute(async (db) => {
        return await db.collection('_User')
            .findOne({_id: userId});
    });

    await mongoExecute(async (db) => {
        return await db.collection('_User')
            .updateOne({_id: userId}, {
                $set: {
                    banned: true,
                    _acl: {},
                    _wperm: [],
                    _rperm: [],

                    acl_original: user._acl,
                    wperm_original: user._wperm,
                    rperm_original: user._rperm
                }
            });
    });

    await mongoExecute(async (db) => {
        return await db.collection('_Session')
            .remove({_p_user: `_User$${userId}`});
    });

    await mongoExecute(async (db) => {
        return await db.collection('_Installation')
            .remove({userId: userId});
    });

    res.json({});
}
```

2) Unban user:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
import * as randomstring from 'randomstring';
import { createReportQuery } from './reportQuery';
import mongoExecute from 'helpers/mongo';

export async function handleUnbanUserRequest(req, res) {

    const userId = req.body.userId;
    if (!userId) {
        res.status(400).send('User id cant be empty');
        return;

    }

    const user = await mongoExecute(async (db) => {
        return await db.collection('_User')
            .findOne({_id: userId});
    });

    await mongoExecute(async (db) => {
        return await db.collection('_User')
            .updateOne({_id: userId}, {
                $set: {
                    banned: false,
                    _acl: user.acl_original,
                    _wperm: user.wperm_original,
                    _rperm: user.rperm_original,
                },

                $unset: {
                    acl_original: 1,
                    wperm_original: 1,
                    rperm_original: 1
                }
            });
    });

    res.json({});
}
```

and Parse server beforeSave check:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, async function (request, response) {
    var user = request.object

    if (user.id == null) {
        user.set('admin', false)
        user.set('premium', false)
        user.set('credits', 0)
        user.set('matches', [])
    }
    else if (!request.master) {
    if (user.dirty('banned'))
        return response.error('You cant set the banned')

    if (user.dirty('acl_original'))
        return response.error('You cant set the acl_original')

    if (user.dirty('wperm_original'))
        return response.error('You cant set the wperm_original')

    if (user.dirty('rperm_original'))
        return response.error('You cant set the rperm_original')
    }

    response.success()
}
```